# tools for the local storage

Tags: .net, html

I am trying to develop a web application which basically gets some details in the form of a for and saves the details in the user's computer. I cant save the data in the server as it is confidential. So all the data should be saved in the local system and should be loaded from the local system. An interface has to be displayed to show/edit delete the data/records.

I am confused what technology to use. I thought of using HTML 5 local storage to store the data and please suggest if there is any easy and appropriate tool/technology which I can use which solves the purpose.

Comment: LocalStorage does exactly what you're looking for.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I assumed that local storage saves only text.just wondering if I can save json objects.

Comment: sorry I meant javascript objects.. like arrays etc..

Comment: You just answered your own question.  Convert them to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the data in the users browser using Cookies with a very long timeset, if it's just text. But the user can always delete the cookies or use an extension that prevents you from storing cookies.

You didn't say what you are using for back-end but I will assume you are using .ASP as .NET is one of your hashtags, you can do this using ASP.

EDIT: You can also use localStorage that is compatible with HTML5, I suggest you read up on localStorage documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

This question might help you decide if localStorage or Cookies is more convenient. 
[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies?rq=1)

Comment: I am using .Net as by backend and I want to create data structures and store data. User'w will create records and save them,

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is good for store datas. There are many libs that use localstorage like [OhMyCache](https://github.com/ozee31/ohmycache) for store objects, arrays...